# I need to filter contents of my text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that I want to loop through, slice some contents, and store in a separate list. The text file contains:

```
blu sre
before we start
start the process
blah blah
blah blha
end the process
blah böah
start the process
blah blah
blah blha
end the process
start the process
blah blah
end the process
blah
```

I want to catch all text between `'start the process'` and `'end the process'` and store in a new list so that each line of the list will contain every text between start the process and end the process. 
The desired new list should be like this

```
list[0] start the process  
blah blah  
blah blha  
end the process   
list[1] start the process  
blah blah  
blah blha  
end the process   
list[2] start the process  
blah blah  
end the process
```

Here is the code I prepared. I don't why its not giving me the required result.

```
list = []
text = 'start the process'
text2 = 'end the process'
for pattern in range (len(file)):
    if text in file[pattern]:
        x = pattern
    if text2 in file[pattern]:
        y = pattern
    list[i]= file[x:y]
 i = i+1
```

Comment: what is `file` in this snippet? is it a file object, the list of lines? The whole text as a single str?

Comment: Which part of your code do you suspect being at fault? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: It is a list of lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is built for that.

```py
import re

part = re.compile(r"start the process(.*?)end the process", flags=re.DOTALL)
wirh open("my_file.text", "r") as file:
    data = file.read()

results = list(part.findall(data))
```

EDIT update code based on @Xosrov comment

Comment: I think you would also need to add ```re.DOTALL``` flag to match all the lines. And make the regex ```r"start_the_process(.*?)end_theprocess"``` to match the first end statement.

Comment: @Florian Bernard tried the code but it gave me an empty string. opened the files recently with read lines

Comment: ```   import re
part = re.compile(r"start_the_process(.*)end_theprocess")
with open(file_list[19], 'r') as f: #open the file 
        file = (f.readlines())
        results = list(part.findall(file)) ```

Comment: Even when i used the read instead of readlines, i didnt get the expected results

Comment: @Xosrov can you write a sample code of how i can apply the do all for this case

Comment: @smomajay Perfect, dont forget to put my awser as validate.

Comment: @Florian Bernard How do i do that ?

Comment: @smomajay Under the up/down vote button, there is a check button, click on it, this well mark the awser as approved. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

@Florian Bernard et al

My requirements has somewhat changed as i am  working on a dataframe.
i want to loop through the data frame and slice the data with conditions and store all values between the start and stop index in an array or a new dataframe's first line.
so if there are 4 occurrences of my start and stop then they should be 4 lines in my array or dataframe.

NB. my dataframe has just one column with texts

here is some code i have done

```
corpus = []
count = 0  
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if df['row'].str.match('start'):
        start = index
    if df['row'].str.match('stop'):
        stop = index
    corpus[count] = df.loc[start:stop]  
    count += 1
```