# I need repitition in slicing my dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

My requirements has somewhat changed as i am working on a dataframe. i want to loop through the data frame and slice the data with conditions and store all values between the start and stop index in an array or a new dataframe's first line. so if there are 4 occurrences of my start and stop then they should be 4 lines in my array or dataframe.

NB. my dataframe has just one column with texts

here is some code i have done

```
corpus = []
count = 0  
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if df['row'].str.match('start'):
        start = index
    if df['row'].str.match('stop'):
        stop = index
    corpus[count] = df.loc[start:stop]  
    count += 1
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is a follow-up to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58473462/i-need-to-filter-contents-of-my-text-file)? That's fine, but I don't think the user you're pinging here will get a notification. You may need to ping them in a comment on their answer in the other question.

Comment: Yes it is a follow up. ill do just that.